# All possible set operations between sets

Tags: combinatorics, boolean-algebra

I was looking for some sort of generalization on set operations between different sets, and how that number of operations increases as the number of set increase as well. It can also be thought as the number of sets represented in a Venn diagram of n sets.
I'm not really sure how to put this into words so i think an example could be more clear.

Number of sets 2, let them be $A$ and $B$, then you have the following set operations in the Venn diagram:
$A\cap B, A\cup B, A - B $ and $B - A$

If the number of sets is 3, $A, B$ and $C$, you will have:
$A-(B \cup C)$,
$(A \cap C)-B$, 
$B-(A \cup C)$, 
$A \cap B \cap C$,
$(A \cap C) - B$, 
$(B \cap C) - A,$
$C -(A \cup B)$ and their complements.

If the number of set is 4: $A, B, C$, and $D$:
$A - (B \cup D \cup C)$,
$(A \cap B) - (D \cup C)$,
$B - (A \cup D \cup C)$,
$D - (A \cup B \cup C)$,
$(B \cap D) - (A \cup C)$,
$(A \cap D \cap B) - C$,
$(A \cap D) - (B \cup C)$,
$(D \cap C \cap A) - B$,
$A \cap B \cap D \cap C$,
$(D \cap B \cap C) - A$,
$(D \cap C) - (A \cup B)$,
$C - (A \cup B \cup D)$,
$(C \cap B) -(A \cup D)$,
$(A \cap B \cap C) - D$,
$(A \cap C)-(B \cup D)$ and their complements.

I'm not sure if this a set theory problem or a combinatory problem, but I would like to know a way to generalize this to obtain the possible combinations of operations between sets a little bit larger, like 6, 8 or 10. to be able to compare the different elements present in those sets.

Comment: Not set theory. I have removed the tag.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is the number of Boolean functions (aka *truth functions*) of $n$ variables. Equivalently, the number of truth tables with $n$ variables and an arbitrary extra column for the value of the function.

The number of assignments of values to $n$ variables is $2^n$, so the number of truth functions is $2^{2^n}$.

Comment: Ok, this confused me a little, when you talk about variables those are the same as the sets that I talked before. In that case, for two sets, there are 16 operations between them?

Comment: Yes, the "sets" $A,B, C, ...$ are just variables figuring in Boolean functions involving the $\cap, \cup, \setminus$ operators and the universe $U$ (so you can form the complement of a set $A$ relative to the universe: $U\setminus A$). These correspond exactly to truth functions using the "complete" set of connectives $\land, \lor, \neg$. Yes there are 16 Boolean operations involving two sets, just as there are 16 Boolean functions of 2 variables.

Comment: And then to find all the possible functions, it would be the combination  between the variables and the operators (with replacement for the operators) and only use an operator if there is a variable to apply to it, is that right?

Comment: I *think* so — I'm actually not sure what you mean. Considering 3 variables $(p,q,r)$, the following all denote Boolean functions of 3 variables: $p, q, r, p\land q\land r, (p\land q)\lor \neg r, \neg q, p\land \neg q$. I don't know what you mean by "only use an operator if there is a variable to apply to it" -- apply a variable to an operator?? We usually think of operators as applying to, operating on, variables.

Comment: My bad, I'm not very fluent with English and sometimes I made those mistakes, and yes I wanted to say what you said, is to apply the operand on the variable rather than the opposite, which was what i wrote.